# Grails Domain Class with Map and Mysql DB

Tags: grails, grails-orm

```
class Author {
    Map books // map of ISBN:book names
}
def a = new Author()
a.books = ["1590597583":"Grails Book"]
a.save()
```

Can anyone can explain, how Author Table will look and what relation to Book,

Answer (score 0):

That's rather not possible, I would do a List of other objects (or hasMany relation), e.g.

```
class Book {
    String isbn
    String title
}
```

that's more flexible and extensible comparing to a Map.Entry where you are limited to key and value, and you can't add any other property

Comment: It is perfectly possible - http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#basicCollectionTypes. You should edit your answer to be correct.

Comment: and where does it say anything about Maps?

Answer (score 0):

Grails will create a table for you called `author` that will look like this:

```
id | version
1  | 1
2  | 2
...
```

You will also get another table called `author_books` that contains key-value pairs from your `books` map and looks like this:

```
books    | books_idx | books_elt
authorId | someKey   | someValue
```

As @Kamil Mikolajczyk says though, your model will usually be easier to understand if you use a collection of `Book` objects.